# IMAP email not persisting read status and reply status - what could be the likely cause?

Tags: email, email-server, hosting, imap, transip

So I have the following setup:

- IMAP mail from TransIP (a pretty big host in the Netherlands)
- Thunderbird on my PC
- Mail on IOS phone

Frequently when I'm reading emails on my PC they are being marked as **Unread** again after a while. Same as emails that I replied to: the **Reply Icon** just dissappears while I can find the email back in sent mails.

As you understand this is highly annoying. I can't trust my inbox anymore and have to doublecheck everything.

I have mailed TransIP and they blamed it on Thunderbird - what I think is a pretty cheap cop out - as Thunderbird is a widely used tool. TransIP is also quite a big host in the Netherlands though, so I also believe this is not a problem for *all* of their users as that would stand out.

As this happens frequently - but not always - it's difficult to make quarantined tests.

Don't know if it's related, but a few times per week (but not often) I'm getting Server errors when it tries to save save the email to the Sent Messages folder. If I click retry it usually succeeds.

Switching host, or mail clients and/or disabling my phone mail client has all quite a big time investment, because I have six inboxes (for various companies) and responding fast to emails is important for my business.

I'm looking for any clues that can sent me in the right direction.

- is this problem familiar to anyone?
- is there anything I can take a look into?
- could this i.e. be wrong settings or anything?
- how big are the odds that it's to do with IOS Mail or Thunderbird?
- if it's the Webhost - is there any leverage that I can have to make sure they look into this problem themselves and fix their stuff?

Comment: Do they offer a webmail client you can connect to? Do you see the same behavior of you reply or mark messages read from the IOS device?

Comment: I think I do - I'll do some tests and let you know.

Comment: Hi @JonAngliss, I've just had it again. I did read my mail through Thunderbird, email was *read*, then later automatically set to *unread* again. When I go to my webmail it was also there set to *unread* there. In the webmail I did see the 'replied' icon there. So for some reason the reply did get persisted but the *read* not (or was being reverted).